# Unable to connect to HBase stand alone server from windows remote client

Tags: hbase

I have my HBase standalone server on centos virtual machine, and my client is on windows desktop. Can I connect to the HBase standalone server remotely without installing HBase on windows ? If yes , Here are the following files

### /etc/hosts file

172.16.108.1    CentOS60-64     # Added by NetworkManager
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
172.29.36.32       localhost.localdomain   localhost

172.29.36.32    534CentOS64-0

### hbase-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
                <value>file:///root/Desktop/HBase/hbase</value>
        </property>


        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
                <value>/root/Desktop/HBase/zookeeper</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
                <value>62181</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>172.29.36.32</value>
        </property>

</configuration>
```

### /conf/regrionservers file

localhost
172.29.36.32

### Code Snippet to connect to HBase server

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "172.29.36.32");
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "62181");

        // Creating Admin
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);

        // Creating Table Descriptor

        HTableDescriptor describe =admin.getTableDescriptor(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf("emp"));

        // Fetching all column families
        Set<byte[]> ColumnFamily = describe.getFamiliesKeys();

        // Listing Out the all column families
        System.out.println(ColumnFamily.size());
        Iterator<byte[]> it=ColumnFamily.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(Bytes.toString(it.next()));
        }
```

--- When I tried to run above code, Its taking too long time to run and raising error as .... unknown host: localhost.localdomain

--- I was able to connect to following url :-
http://172.29.36.32:60010/master-status
PS:- I will be thankful if someone can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is late but I hope that it could help someone.
The problem in your case may be /etc/hosts file. I think you should remove the following line:

172.29.36.32 localhost.localdomain localhost

Also, If you are connecting to a remote HBase cluster - make sure to add **all** of cluster hostnames and ip's to your local hosts file (/etc/hosts on Linux or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows), like that:

172.16.108.1 CentOS60-64

172.29.36.32 534CentOS64-0

Apparently Zookeper uses hostname instead of ip somewhere when trying to connect to HBase and it can be a problem when connecting remotely with Java.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should modify your `/etc/hosts` file. Give you an example.

> [your ip can be accessed remote] [your domain will be used by remote server ]
>   [your ip same as last row ] [your hostname which can get by command `hostname`]

and the `domain` and `hostname` should not be appear on other line mapping other ip addresses.

After that, the client will use the `domain` to access your hbase server.You can get that information in the log.

you can check by the following code.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
       System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName());
}
}
```