# Not able to connect to HBase ( Zookeeper ) running on Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, hbase, apache-zookeeper, vagrant-windows

I have simple vagrant machine which has a stand alone instance on HBase. When I start the hbase, I'm able to access to access the hbase information URL http://192.168.99.101:16010/master-status.

But when I try to connect through java, I'm not able to connect to Zookeeper.

Vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hbase-phoenix"  # A simple HBase phoenix box
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false
  config.vm.define "hbase_pnx" do |hbase_pnx|
    hbase_pnx.vm.hostname = "hbasepnx"
    hbase_pnx.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.99.101"
    hbase_pnx.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2181, host: 2181
    hbase_pnx.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 16010, host: 16010
  end
end
```

The host file on the VM looks like

```
vagrant@hbasepnx:~$ cat /etc/hosts
192.168.99.101  hbasepmx        hbasepnx
192.168.99.101  hbase-vm        hbase-vm
192.168.99.101  localhost
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

hbase-site.xml looks like

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/vagrant/data/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/vagrant/data/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Simple test code looks like

```
public void testHBaseCRUD() throws Exception {
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.99.101");
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        try (HTable htable = new HTable(config, tableName)) {
            int total = 100;
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                int userid = i;
                String email = "user-" + i + "@foo.com";
                String phone = "555-1234";

                byte[] key = Bytes.toBytes(userid);
                Put put = new Put(key);

                put.add(Bytes.toBytes(familyName), Bytes.toBytes("FIRST_NAME"), Bytes.toBytes(email));  // <-- email goes here
                put.add(Bytes.toBytes(familyName), Bytes.toBytes("LAST_NAME"), Bytes.toBytes(phone));  // <-- phone goes here
                htable.put(put);

        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("inserted " + total + " users  in " + (t2 - t1) + " ms");

    }
```

Hbase version is hbase-1.1.9

```
2017-03-28 10:06:01,422 INFO  [main-SendThread(192.168.99.101:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:primeConnection(852)) - Socket connection established to 192.168.99.101/192.168.99.101:2181, initiating session
2017-03-28 10:06:01,427 INFO  [main-SendThread(192.168.99.101:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:onConnected(1235)) - Session establishment complete on server 192.168.99.101/192.168.99.101:2181, sessionid = 0x15b1534b9900009, negotiated timeout = 40000
2017-03-28 10:06:50,084 INFO  [hconnection-0x4206a205-metaLookup-shared--pool2-t1] client.RpcRetryingCaller (RpcRetryingCaller.java:callWithRetries(142)) - Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=48438 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'user,    ,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hbasepmx,37628,1490709431477, seqNum=0
2017-03-28 10:07:02,605 INFO  [hconnection-0x4206a205-metaLookup-shared--pool2-t1] client.RpcRetryingCaller (RpcRetryingCaller.java:callWithRetries(142)) - Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=60963 ms ago, cancelled=true, msg=row 'user,    ,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hbasepmx,37628,1490709431477, seqNum=0
2017-03-28 10:07:48,168 INFO  [hconnection-0x4206a205-metaLookup-shared--pool2-t2] client.RpcRetryingCaller (RpcRetryingCaller.java:callWithRetries(142)) - Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=46421 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'user,    ,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hbasepmx,37628,1490709431477, seqNum=0
2017-03-
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this question has an answer in 
[Unable to connect to HBase stand alone server from windows remote client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751187/unable-to-connect-to-hbase-stand-alone-server-from-windows-remote-client)

The problem is Zookeeper only connects using host-name and not IP

so in my Windows host file I need to add

```
192.168.99.101  hbasepmx        hbasepnx
192.168.99.101  hbase-vm        hbase-vm
```

And in the code the change is ,

```
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbase-vm");
```